# Android default notification margin of Xiaomi Phone

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am using a Custom Notification and finding a way to set its margin/padding based on the phone's default value.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/notification_custom_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
</LinearLayout>
```

I found some answers here: [Android default notification margin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54947738/android-default-notification-margin)

I tested on Virtual Devices and some phone models ( Samsung, Oppo, Pixel) , the method seems to work well except for Xiaomi Phone, the padding is very big, maybe 5-6 times bigger than other phones.I think there is a problem with the setViewPadding method since the value `int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(identifier);` is not so much different from other phones.
Please let me know if you have any idea and where can I find the android dimen xml file in system folder?

```
 RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.my_notification_content_layout);
try {
    // We are assuming start and end are same. If we want to be nitty, we will get them separately, and then check which to use for left and which for righht.
    int identifier = context.getResources().getIdentifier("notification_content_margin_start", "dimen", "android");
    if (identifier != 0) {
        int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(identifier);
        contentView.setViewPadding(R.id.notify_layout, padding, 0, padding, 0);
        Log.d("setViewPadding", "Setting padding to: " + padding);
    } else {
        Log.d("setViewPadding", "Failed to find padding");
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.d("setViewPadding", "Failed to set padding");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have exactly same issue and was hoping someone would answer. Meanwhile, though not a direct solution, the following may nevertheless help.

Instead of using a *fully* customized layout, define `DecoratedCustomView` as follows:

```
builder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle());
```

What this does is it keeps system-default *header* of the notification, including app icon, app name, and default **margins**  (Tested on MIUI 12). You can still set your custom layout as you would normally do:

```
builder.setCustomContentView(notificationLayout);
```

The advantage of this method is that also gets a 1:1 system header (even on MIUI), while keeping custom main layout, which is hard to do with fully custom layout. It also eliminates need to check default notification padding. Further things to keep in mind:

1. This works only for API24+. Below API24, old notification style was used (big full height icon) so this *will* compile, but won't work like you would expect it to.
2. Make sure you *remove* all padding from your layout, as well as custom set *app icon* and *app title*, as these will be defined for you.
3. Although this way you cannot change notification title (app name), it may be very handy to add *subtitle* as follows: `builder.setSubText("Secondary Title");` See example in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49393522/android-notification-add-text-after-apps-name-before-when/49393719) post

Example how the transformation looks like.

This is fully customized layout (bare in mind, displays perfectly on literally any device, but MIUI).

[image: Screenshot]

Here, `DecoratedCustomView` is used. You can see that the header is perfectly aligned (hotspot notification for comparison), and the only difference is that app name isn't colored anymore.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for your help. I had tried your solution before I posted this question. But Icons is not fully displayed the same as your first picture, I have to touch a downward arrow to extend the notification to fully display icon, it is very annoying to user.

Comment: In case you have downward arrow, that means notification layout height exceeds 'small_notification' size. Try decreasing size of your notification so it fits to androids standard sizes ([google](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/custom-notification) claims it may be as small as 48dp).

Comment: If the issue only affects *app icon* and not the actual notification, most probably you have wrong icon sizing. Make sure you used [this](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html#source.type=clipart&source.clipart=ac_unit&source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&name=ic_stat_ac_unit), or similar icon generator to produce multiple assets. One icon is not enough.

Comment: "In case you have downward arrow, that means notification layout height exceeds 'small_notification' size. Try decreasing size of your notification so it fits to androids standard sizes (google claims it may be as small as 48dp)" -> This is very helpful for me.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will use another layout that fits androids standard sizes.