# Android Custom Notification is Cropped by Xiaomi

Tags: android, notifications, android-11, android-fullscreen, xiaomi

I implement Custom Notification with `.setStyle(NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle())`
It is working properly for all devices except Xiaomi Mi 11 Lite.

When there is an incoming call, the application shows notification with `fullScreenIntent`. You can see image for that notification(cropped notification' s screenshot):

[image: Cropped Image]

If i scroll/tap the notification it looks like that(normal notification' s screenshot):

[image: Normal Image]

I implement all types of customContent
`setCustomBigContentView`,
`setCustomHeadsUpContentView`,
`setCustomContentView`" and
it works properly for all other devices.

Is there anybody who encountered the same error?

Comment: Pls Follow this link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/69780737